# How to manage current time exist between start time and end time

Tags: php, codeigniter, timezone

I have some predefined cases:
1. Need to take start time and end time in current time zone.
2. Need to store current time and end time in UTC format.
3. Need to check current time of a user exist between set/stored UTC start time and end time.

I have tried with many case.

But in every cases I found some wholes due to timezone problem.

Please share an example with keep in mind that user time zone may be Asia/kolkata or America/New york.

Comment: Try carbon: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ Best way to work with DateTime Objects in PHP

Comment: Timezone are quite a big deal in every language. I suggest using an external librairy to manage them. In PHP i like [momentPHP](https://github.com/fightbulc/moment.php). It's a quite easy to use library. Might worth looking at.

Comment: I have read Date time objects in PHP, But here is case that I have only start time and end time in user current time zone and I need to find out that if any user comes from other timezone that that can also can check that current time is exist between start time and end time.

Comment: Just...I need a logic, I will implement that..

Answer (score 0):

in php there is to set the time zone is y that function 
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
echo date_default_timezone_get();
its not a authentic answer but which i have knowledge about this i tell you .. by this function we set the time zone